# Форма создания новой страницы на сайте

Tags: html, css

Можно ли средствами HTML CSS js сделать страницу добавления нового товара/поста/новости? 
Аля как тут - нажимаешь кнопку "задать вопрос", пишешь вопрос, отправляешь и для него создаётся отдельная страница с сохранением стилей сайта. Или это как-то с помощью РНР делается? 
Подскажите, как сформулировать этот вопрос правильно, чтоб загуглить его. Ещё подскажите, как этот вопрос нагуглить на английском, что-то не находится. Пробовал искать по page generator, но находится совсем не то, что я ищу.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PowgRqd - типа этого ?

Comment: Создать можно, только пост не добавится. А чтоб добавился - надо php и еще куда-то записать пост (например в БД). Гугли PHP Form Handling